# React Native Unable to fetch multiple documents data from Firebase firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

[image: Please Check the image, I have not get the second part]

**App.js File** this is App.js file, Please check the below code and correct me I don't have any idea how to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

*.doc("2E3kDAa0QzqoQuoBK1T9", "vROxKUSgcNWwlt7cDEKV")* on this line I get the issue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
function App() {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    getDatabase();
  }, []);
const getDatabase = async () => {
try {
      const data = await firestore()
        .collection('myCollection')
        .doc("2E3kDAa0QzqoQuoBK1T9", "vROxKUSgcNWwlt7cDEKV")
        .get();
      setMyData(data._data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>First:-{myData ? myData.name : 'Loading...'}</Text>
      <Text>Second:-{myData ? myData.secondData : 'Loading...'}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work:

```
.doc("2E3kDAa0QzqoQuoBK1T9", "vROxKUSgcNWwlt7cDEKV")
```

If you check the API docs for [`CollectionReference.doc`](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/collectionreference#doc) it expects:

> ```
> doc(documentPath?: undefined | string): DocumentReference<>;
> ```

So you can pass in a single document ID or path, not multiple.

---

If you want to return multiple documents by their ID, you can use th [`in` query operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) on the [`FieldPath.documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) to do so for up to 10 values. If you have more values, you'll need to retrieve them in batches of up to 10 and merge them in your application code.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I appreciate your prompt response. Actually, I am at a beginner level in this field, so I don't have any idea how to use "in query operator ". Is there any other simple way to fetch data from Firebase? I would like to change the whole code if this process is difficult.

Comment: I linked the documentation for the `in` operator, so recommend giving it a try. It's bound to be simpler than changing the whole code.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank, Please check my updated code here in the link below ↓ . though I have not get any errors but It's still not working.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73273391/firebase-react-native-not-fetching-multiple-docs-from-firestore